Japanese citizen living in the UK, pays tax in Japan, do they need to pay tax in the UK too? Double tax?
My wife is working part time earning under £800 a month and paying taxes in Japan on her income. She lives in the UK though, I believe there's a tax agreement with Japan to prevent double taxation. Does she need to do anything over here? She's worked for this company for 6 months now, I'm beginning to get concerned we're missing something here.

Why is she paying taxes in Japan? Is she working for a Japanese employer? Is she legally allowed to work in the UK? I ask because remote work is still considered 'work' for purposes of work Visas etc., which is something often missed in cases like this.

She is working for a Japanese employer. She is on a Spousal visa so is legally allowed to work. Sorry should have clarified


Does she need to do anything over here

Most likely.
The tax treaties between countries do indeed exist and attempt to address the issue of double taxation, but this is not trivial. If there's a treaty between the UK and Japan, it would define what income should be taxed by whom in what order, and if there are any treaty benefits in either country - the taxpayer would need to actively claim them.
Generally, income earned in a country is sourced to that country, meaning that country has the first right to tax it. So if a treaty says that only one country should tax it - most likely in this case that would be the UK, not Japan.
However, there may be specific provisions that change that depending on the type of income, and the purposes of stay. For example, students may be treated differently than long term foreign employees.
I suggest to speak with a UK based tax advisor who'd be able to analyze the treaty and propose how to apply it in your case.

Probably income in Japan is automatically deducted from her salary, which makes it hard to make the employer stop deducting it and send it to UK so she can pay her taxes in UK. I'm in a similar situation even though country names are different, it's hard to stop automatic tax payments and do it manually elsewhere.

@uylmz I'm assuming the employer is unaware the employee is in a different country? The employer in this situation is also in violation of the UK/wherever-you-are labor and tax laws. Generally, remote work would not allowed as an employee unless you become an employee of the local entity of your employer.

"unless you become an employee of the local entity of your employer." or if she works as a subcontractor which means she gets the gross payment and has to handle taxes herself, both resolves her tax situation?

@uylmz right, but for contractors you wouldn't usually have a withholding issue. You might have a VAT issue, instead. Although I don't know how it works in Japan. In some countries there are also laws preventing converting employees into subcontractors (e.g.: the US).

This is pretty concerning. For further clarification her employer is well aware of her location in the UK. They hire people across the globe to teach english through minecraft servers to kids. She signed a contract of sorts and they had to check some stuff with regarding her living in the UK.

@Josh19041996 Are you sure she is considered an 'employee'? I am not familiar at all with Japanese tax / labour rules, but often what you are describing would be considered a 'contractor relationship'. That likely makes things simpler for you. In fact it is not clear to me that she has any tax obligations to Japan at all, as often such income would be taxed primarily in the country where the work is performed [where she physically sits while doing the teaching], with tax money owed to the employer's country of residence [Japan] only in specific situations.

@Grade'Eh'Bacon Thanks your reply. You're correct I just checked and she's a contractor employee with an end date they renew. I just checked what she's paying out and it looks to be only pension and health insurance in Japan. No taxes, so I assume this means we 100% need to be filling in some kind of UK tax return thing?

@Josh19041996 This is not a full answer, I have not researched the specifics of the UK-Japan tax treaty, so take this as a starting point only: probably your wife only owes tax to the UK, and no tax owed to Japan. You would need to file as a UK... 'resident' [not sure if they use that term precisely], but note that tax 'residency' <> immigration 'residency', so even if you are not considered a resident for other purposes, you may be considered a resident for tax purposes. Look up 'how to file taxes in UK as a self-employed person'.

Also - you may want to research whether your wife would actually be eligible to receive pension / benefits in Japan for the amounts being withheld; it is possible the withholdings are not necessary because your wife may not be eligible for benefits. I have no idea if that is true, though. Just a hunch worth investigating.

@Grade'Eh'Bacon Greatly appreciated. Thank you for the start I feel like we at least know that we need to be sorting it out rather than leaving it and hoping for the best.
